# Mysql BIGINT comparison not evaluating correctly

Tags: mysql

So I've been having a problem and either I am forgetting something fundamental or I found a bug. I've narrowed it down to this:

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestmp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Simple. My query:

```
insert into tbl (id, timestmp) values (1, 1)
on duplicate key update timestmp = if(values(timestmp) > timestmp,
values(timestmp), timestmp)
```

Table will contain

```
(1, 1)
```

Repeat the query with

```
values (1, 2)
```

Table will contain

```
(1, 2)
```

Repeat the query with

```
values (1, 1)
```

Table will *still* contain

```
(1, 2)
```

Great. Just what we want. Instead with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestmp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Let's do the same queries:

```
insert into tbl (id, timestmp) values (1, 1)
on duplicate key update timestmp = if(values(timestmp) > timestmp,
values(timestmp), timestmp)
```

Table contains:

```
(1, 1)
```

Query with:

```
values (1, 2)
```

Table contains:

```
(1, 1)
```

What? Let's try

```
values (1, -1)
```

Table contains:

```
(1, -1)
```

JKLFSD!!!!! What's going on? Is this supposed to happen? Am I completely misinterpreting something? Do I need a special function for bigint comparison?

Comment: I created the table and ran the inserts and it worked normally.

Comment: Looks like a signed/unsigned problem. Maybe Bigint is not signed and -1 will cause an integer over/underflow.

Comment: @LucasHenrique well that is awkward.

Comment: @HectorLector But the (1, 2) query isn't working either.

Comment: But I tested dropping the -1 and also functioned normally.

Comment: Insert (1,3) and then tried to (1,2). Thus it shows correctly (1,3)

Comment: @Tillerino Just saw that. Maybe when you just write "1" it is converted to an int or something like this. Try inserting the values with CAST as bigint.

Comment: Try FLUSH TABLES `tbl`. That to close the open table, forces the table in use to be closed, and flushes the query cache.

Comment: Since it seemed to work for all of you guys, I went ahead and updated mysql on my machine and it fixed the problem. Thanks for the quick comments!